How can management efficiently handle 10 servers with the same stack?
I have a problem with my server structure.
I have a scraper script on more than 10 servers.
btw. This server is on a different provider, etc.
Currently, I am installing the same library on each server, setting up the repository on each instance, committing changes on one instance, and then updating all servers.
I have to log in via SSH to each server to run the same commands. My stack includes Ubuntu 22.04 and Docker Compose on each instance.
How can I automate my workflow for easy management without overengineering?
I am thinking about Ansible, but maybe there is a simpler, easier solution?

Ansible is simple and easy solution, actully.

There’s many ways to skin a cat! Ansibe, Chef, and Puppet are probably the most widely used ones for what you’re intended to do. You might  want to start with monitoring only adding custom script-based management later. For monitoring Zabbix and Nagios are coming to the mind.

All admin tasks, especially inventory, install and setup like this, should be scripted. To know what the previous person was doing, and repeat the procedure without error. That previous person could be you.
Basic place to start is writing down the commands to do into shell scripts. Make them run non interactively, and add some comments explaining what's going on. Commit to version control. If you use zero of the fancy automation frameworks, scripts alone are a huge help in consistently doing tasks.
Ansible can run arbitrary commands (scripts) using your existing remote shell access, on multiple hosts at once.  Take the scripts you wrote previously and run them as-is with Ansible script module. Put these 10 hosts in a basic plain text inventory, and you can do all of them at once via ssh.
Other automation systems exist. Evaluating them is a matter of reviewing their systems for inventory of hosts, running commands, and what tasks they can do.
